# I can't install PHP on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm pretty new in AWS, I've tried to install PHP on my virtual machine, but it doesn't works, I get the error:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx user]# yum install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 mysql-
server php5-mysql
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package apache2 available.
No package libapache2-mod-php5 available.
No package php5 available.
No package mysql-server available.
No package php5-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I don't know the reason of this, I already tried the comamnd *yum update*, but it doesn't help, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP5 is quite old and is probably not available anymore in the YUM package manager.

Also I think the tutorial you are using is Debian/Ubuntu based.
Apache2 is called httpd24 in yum for instance.

That would look something like this:

```
sudo yum install -y httpd24 php72 mysql57-server php72-mysqlnd
```

Or if you are using the Amazon Linux 2 image, then use this command:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
```

To find out which specific image you are running:

```
cat /etc/system-release
```

Please check out the AWS documentation for an up-to-date tutorial on howto deploy your own LAMP-server:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Comment: Ohh, I used your command but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Then you are probably using a different AWS Linux image.

Try this command:

sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2